# In Flex Builder, what's the shortcut key to switch perspective?

Tags: actionscript, flexbuilder

Hi anyone know? In Flex Builder, what's the shortcut key to switch perspective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl+F8 to switch perspectives is the default shortcut for Flash Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to set a shortcut under Preferences -> General -> Keys -> Show Perspective {perspective name}